# iOS 11 inputAccessoryView broken

Tags: swift3, ios11, inputaccessoryview

I have the following set up for my UIToolBar / Accessory View on a view controller

```
@IBOutlet var inputFieldView: UIToolbar!
override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool{
    return true
}

override var inputAccessoryView: UIView?{
    return self.inputFieldView
}
```

then inside my viewDidLoad I have:

```
    let seperator = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0 , y: 0, width: ScreenSize.width(), height: 1))
    seperator.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightBackground
    self.inputFieldView.addSubview(seperator)
    self.inputFieldView.isTranslucent = false
    self.inputFieldView.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
    self.inputFieldView.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
    self.inputFieldView.removeFromSuperview()
```

This worked great for ios versions 10 and 9.  It is a text view with a "Send" button.  It sits at the bottom of the screen and when pressed, becomes first responder allowing the keyboard to come up and it positions itself correctly.

With ios 11 i cannot even click on it when it is at the bottom, so I cannot type at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. It looks like UIToolbar's just are not working correctly in iOS 11.

Changed it to an UIView and removed

```
self.inputFieldView.isTranslucent = false
self.inputFieldView.setShadowImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any)
self.inputFieldView.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(), forToolbarPosition: .any, barMetrics: .default)
```

got it working (and changed it to a UIView from UIToolbar in the xib as well.)

Comment: Can you show your complete code please. I am struggling to get it to show up at all.

Comment: Are you trying to re-create my issue, or solve an issue of your own? @arvidurs

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug on iOS 11. UIToolbar subviews don't get the touch events because some internal views to the toolbar aren't properly setup.

**The current workaround is to call toolBar.layoutIfNeeded() right before adding subviews.**

In your case:

```
inputFieldView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hopefully this will get fixed on the next major version.

Comment: @ahbou Do you know if there's a radar filed for this? I'd like to track it if it's possible