# iOS11/Xcode 9 UIBarButtonItem Issue

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, xcode9, clickable

UIBarbutton item does not respond to clicks after I built my app from Xcode 9. Its working on Xcode 8.

Apparently found that there are issues as described in this post below.. ([UIBarButtonItem not clickable on iOS 11 beta 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45854203/uibarbuttonitem-not-clickable-on-ios-11-beta-7))

The problem is I added the constraints as explained in the post and still wont work..Can someone look at my code and tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
UIButton* someButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeInfoLight];
[someButton setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton setFrame:frame];
[someButton setShowsTouchWhenHighlighted:YES];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

NSLayoutConstraint * widthConstraint = [someButton.widthAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30];
NSLayoutConstraint * HeightConstraint =[someButton.heightAnchor constraintEqualToConstant:30];
[widthConstraint setActive:YES];
[HeightConstraint setActive:YES];

UIBarButtonItem *item = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
self.toolbar.items = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:item, nil];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved.. turns out it was [a UIToolbar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371441).

This is a known bug on iOS 11. UIToolbar subviews don't get the touch events because some internal views to the toolbar aren't properly setup.

The current workaround is to call `toolBar.layoutIfNeeded()` right before adding subviews.

In your case:

```
inputFieldView.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Hopefully this will get fixed on the next major version.