# React Native InputAccessoryView not working on iOS 11

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ios11, inputaccessoryview

I have a simple InputAccessoryView of TouchableOpacities to navigate a gradebook table of TextInputs [as pictured here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jtzT.jpg) However, this InputAccessoryView does not respond to touch whatsoever.

After some research, it appears that InputAccessoryViews are broken on iOS 11 without [a workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46371441/ios-11-inputaccessoryview-broken), but does this workaround exist in react native, and if not, is there anything I can do to make this InputAccessoryView work?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issues.  Not even FB's own examples work correctly.  Frustrating ... Did you find a workaround?  :-)

Answer (score 0):

@Caleb I found an example that works: github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/RNTester/js/… The examples in their docs don't work but this code (by FB) actually works on RN 0.57 on iOS 11.4.1. Does it work for you? Good luck!

Here's FB's code:

```
    /**
 * Copyright (c) Facebook, Inc. and its affiliates.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 * @flow
 * @format
 */

'use strict';

const React = require('React');
const ReactNative = require('react-native');
const {
Alert,
Button,
InputAccessoryView,
ScrollView,
StyleSheet,
Text,
TextInput,
View,
} = ReactNative;

class Message extends React.PureComponent<*> {
render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.textBubbleBackground}>
        <Text style={styles.text}>Text Message</Text>
    </View>
    );
}
}

class TextInputBar extends React.PureComponent<*, *> {
state = {text: ''};

render() {
    return (
    <View style={styles.textInputContainer}>
        <TextInput
        style={styles.textInput}
        onChangeText={text => {
            this.setState({text});
        }}
        value={this.state.text}
        placeholder={'Type a message...'}
        />
        <Button
        onPress={() => {
            Alert.alert('You tapped the button!');
        }}
        title="Send"
        />
    </View>
    );
}
}

class InputAccessoryViewExample extends React.Component<*> {
static title = '<InputAccessoryView>';
static description =
    'Example showing how to use an InputAccessoryView to build an iMessage-like sticky text input';

render() {
    return (
    <View>
        <ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="interactive">
        {Array(15)
            .fill()
            .map((_, i) => <Message key={i} />)}
        </ScrollView>
        <InputAccessoryView backgroundColor="#fffffff7">
        <TextInputBar />
        </InputAccessoryView>
    </View>
    );
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
textInputContainer: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
},
textInput: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingLeft: 10,
},
text: {
    padding: 10,
    color: 'white',
},
textBubbleBackground: {
    backgroundColor: '#2f7bf6',
    borderRadius: 20,
    width: 110,
    margin: 20,
},
});

module.exports = InputAccessoryViewExample;
```

I ran this example and can confirm that it works on RN 0.57 and iOS 11.4.1.

Hope this helps!